# Where is this JQuery wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I want to add the click event to all elements where the `id="violacao":

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#violacao').click(function() {
        alert('teste');
    });
});
```

But just the first link responds to the click. This is the HTML generated:

```
<tr>
  <td><a href="#" id="violacao">40954589</a></td>
  <td>Perda de Comunicação</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><a href="#" id="violacao">88692020503</a></td>
  <td>Perda de Comunicação</td>
</tr>
```

When I try this way:

```
jQuery("a").click(function() {
    alert('teste');
});
```

It works fine, except that all links are affected. What is wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

IDs in HTML are meant to be unique (one per document).  Change the ID to a class (and use . instead of #) and it should work.

Comment: and if you have CSS definitions for the id of 'violacao', please adjust accordingly

Answer (score 1):

While what Steve Mason says it's true, the actual problem is not that.

If you change ID to a class a problem persists: all links will get affected.

Instead, if you aim to affect one single <A>, you should do one of the following:

a) Assign unique IDs to each <A>, then do something like you were doing first; or

b) Assign classes and use the :first selector:

```
jQuery("a.violacao:first").click( function (){
  alert('teste');
} );
```

That will apply to the first matching anchor with class violacao. Alternatively, if you want to affect a specific anchor, you could use :eq(index).

For a comprehensive list of selector, visit http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors.

Comment: SebaGR misread the question, I think. Selecting one link is not what the poster wanted, rather it was part of the problem. The class solution is correct in this case, & doesn't select all links. Just wanted to clear that up.

Comment: I don't think so... he said "It works fine, except that all links are affected.", so I believe that "except" word tells us the desired behavior is to select just one anchor.

Comment: The "It works fine, except that all links are affected." comment was after the example where he tries the $('a').click(...) method, obviously this will affect all links. The actual problem was in the first example, which is down to duplicate IDs.

Comment: @Steve: if he changes IDs for classes the same behavior stays... All links will trigger. I bet what he actually did to solve it is assign different IDs as you suggested, which works fine. And that's the point I'm making: changing to == classes doen't solve it; assigning unique IDs does.

Comment: SebaGR: I suggest if you care to discuss this further, go back & read the original question carefully. The desired behavior was to select multiple links that contain a certain identifier - first sentence of the question. Using & selecting by class is the perfect solution, in this case.